# polymorphic arguments in a function pointer in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, casting, polymorphism, function-pointers

Is it possible to safely cast between two function pointer in C++, given that the arguments as polymorphicly equivalent i.e. (example only)

```
class Base {}
class A : Base {}
class B : Base {}
class C : Base {}

template<typename T, typename U>
using FPTR = void (*)(const T&, const U&);

using index = std::pair<std:type_info, std::type_info>;
std::unordered_map<index, FPTR<Base, Base>> func_map;

template<typename T, typename U>
register(FPTR<T,U> fptr) {
   // assert T and U are subclasses of Base
   func_map[index(typeid(T), typeid(U))] = fptr;
}

void call(const Base& first, const Base& second) {
   auto it = func_map.find(index(typeid(first), typeid(second)));
   if (it != func_map.end()) {
        (*it)(first, second)
   }
}

void func1(const A&, const C&) {}

// call these
register<A,C>(func1);
register<B,B>([](const B&, const B&) -> void {});
```

so when invoking call, it would resolve the function to call based on the registered typeids, and the called function would expect the explicit type, effectively casting from the base type.

My thinking is this is going to cause an error at run time because the cast wron't occur correctly. I've considered using a lambda function to wrap fptr, but that would result in an extra indirect call, is there a way to avoid this while correctly performing the cast, note I can't cast in call, because I can only get the typeid/type_info and can't use that with the cast functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an extra direct call, if that's not a problem (the target call might even be in-lineable in the wrapper, depending on your compiler and how the translation units are set up).

Something like:

```
struct Base {}
// ...

template <typename T, typename U>
using FPTR = void (*)(const T&, const U&);

template <typename T, typename U, FPTR<T,U> fptr>
void WrapFPTR(const Base &a, const Base &b)
{
  fptr(static_cast<const T&>(a), static_cast<const U&>(b));
}
```

allows you to store `WrapFPTR<T,U,foo>` which *is* an `FPTR<Base,Base>` at every site where you register a given function `foo`.

If you really need an arbitrary function pointer, you'd need to store a polymorphic closure object with a pointer to that function's concrete type instead.

Comment: I haden't considered that, I would assume C++ would give me an error if I tried putting a suitable lambda function in as the template parameter however, I could define two versions of the register function, and use a closure in the one that takes function pointers as run time arguments. Two questions however, is the static cast necessary here, I though C++ did implicit casting on the function arguments in this case, and second would it be possible to actually do the register using a template to avoid needing the invoke the register function at run-time, possibly defining some static object?

Comment: Another question, for my use case the functions will ONLY be invoked through my mapping, is there a way to tell the compiler the wrapper function is the only call site for the original function and get it to actually inline the code and remove the original definition, I'm assuming this can't be done, but if possible then this solution would be ideal.

Comment: If you define your actual function in a .cpp, particularly in an anonymous namespace, the compiler can at least tell it's not reachable from anywhere else. The wrapper function instance is specific to the wrapped function, so it will _also_ exist only in the translation unit where you register. Give it a try and see what your compiler does.

Answer (score 0):

Current C++ contains no elaborate notion of co(ntra)variance. Can you go with static mapping instead?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};
class A : Base {};
class B : Base {};
class C : Base {};

template<typename T, typename U> using FPTR = void (*)(const T&, const U&);

// instead of allocating a run-time map, create a map on compiler's heap at compile-time
template<typename U, typename V> static FPTR<U const &, V const &> funcMap;

void nyan(A const &, A const &) { std::cout << "Nyan" << std::endl; }
void meow(B const &, B const &) { std::cout << "Meow" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    funcMap<A, A> = nyan;
    funcMap<B, B> = meow;
    funcMap<A, A>(A{}, A{});
}
```

Comment: Dosen't work since I would be calling in a context that only knows about Base, basically calling on each pair of a vector of Base objects, which would be A, B or C but handled through polymorphism, otherwise I could just use overload resolution.

Comment: So an extra action would be need anyway, if you need to store them in type-erased form. A lambda call is not that bad in that aspect.